# Application of coordinate-stretching transformation for Perfectly Matched Layer

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, na.numerical-analysis

A Perfectly Matched Layer (PML) is an absorbing boundary condition (ABC) which can be used to approximate free-field conditions for the numerical solution of wave equation problems.

[PML note](http://www-math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.369/pml.pdf)

The PML is normally applied to a PDE using the following transformation:

$
\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}} \to \frac{1}{{1 + i\frac{{\sigma (x)}}{\omega }}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}
$

In the above, $i = \sqrt { - 1}$ and $\sigma(x)$ is a function of position in the ABC.  Now apparently

$
\frac{{\partial ^2 }}{{\partial x^2 }} \to \frac{1}{s}\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left( {\frac{1}{s}\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}} \right)
$

$
s = 1 + i\frac{{\sigma (x)}}{\omega }
$

But is it possible to apply a coordinate stretching in the following fashion:
$
\frac{{\partial ^2 }}{{\partial x^2 }} \to \frac{1}{u}\frac{{\partial ^2 }}{{\partial x^2 }}
$

The coordinate stretching performed in this fashion would be similar in function to the stretching performed by the transformation applied to $\partial /\partial x$.

Essentially what I would like to do is to apply the coordinate stretching directly to $\partial ^2 /\partial x^2$.  I've looked in the PML literature for a very long time, and it seems that most interest is in the application of the coordinate stretching directly to $\partial /\partial x$.

Moreover, I can imagine the coordinate-stretching occurring in a similar fashion to stretching a rubber sheet.  If the stretching is being done to the coordinates of $\partial /\partial x$, then what is happening to $\partial ^2 /\partial x^2$?

Comment: @Willie: I think that you are right; I'll edit the question above in an attempt to be a little more clear.  Thank you for suggesting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I am not familiar with the PML method to categorically say that it is generally impossible to have an absorbing boundary layer with the second order transform that you seek. But I can say confidently that if you are looking from the point of view of the complex coordinate transformation, then you *cannot* have a transformation that substitutes
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\to \frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} $$
This is because the second coordinate derivative is **not** tensorial in nature.

Let $y_i$ and $x_i$ be two difference coordinate systems for the same domain, such that $y_i = y_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ can be written as functions of $x_j$s. The first derivative of any function is tensorial, in the sense that the coefficients
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{j} \frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_j} $$ 
the matrix $(\partial y_j / \partial x_i)$ is sometimes called the *Jacobian matrix* for the coordinate transformation.

However, the second derivative of functions are, in general, not tensorial. So usually we have
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \neq \sum_{kl} \frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial y_l}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_k \partial y_l}$$
The only exception is when $f$ has a critical point: if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_k} = 0$ for each $k$, then the above expression is actually an equality. In general the action of a coordinate transformation on any higher order (order $>1$) partial differential operator will introduce lower order terms. The best way to explain this is in terms of *connections* on the tangent bundle in the language of differential geometry.

Another way to illustrate this is to consider the case where the underlying domain is one-dimensional, just the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Now let $v$ be any non-vanishing continuous vector field on $\mathbb{R}$, then $v = \phi(x) \partial_x$ for some continuous, non-vanishing coefficient function $\phi$. For any such $v$ we can integrate it to obtain a coordinate function $y$ such that $\partial_y = v$. Now, 
$$ \partial_y^2 f = v(v(f)) = \phi \partial_x(\phi \partial_x f) = \phi^2 \partial_x^2 f + \phi \partial_x\phi \partial_x f$$
And you see that unless $\phi$ is the constant function (in which case $y$ is just a dilation of $x$), in general the second derivative relative to the $y$ coordinate system will depend on first derivatives in the $x$ coordinate system.

This all just goes to say that in general, if you are looking for a transformation that directly substitutes 
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \to \frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} $$
it cannot be obtained by any sort of coordinate transformation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out; this allows me to better understand what I should do next and how I should structure my further research into problems involving the PML. 

Answer (score 0):

The complex contour $\tilde x$ is given by

$
\tilde x(x) = x + if(x)
$

In the above, $x$ is the real part of the contour, $i = \sqrt { - 1}$, and $\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}} = \frac{{\sigma (x)}}{\omega }$

Then

$
\frac{{\partial \tilde x(x)}}{{\partial x}} = 1 + i\frac{{\partial f(x)}}{{\partial x}}
$

$
\frac{{\partial ^2 \tilde x(x)}}{{\partial x^2 }} = i\frac{{\partial ^2 f(x)}}{{\partial x^2 }}
$

Now applying this to the differential along the deformed contour, the transformation becomes:

$
\frac{{\partial ^2 }}{{\partial x^2 }} \to \frac{1}{{i\frac{{\partial ^2 f(x)}}{{\partial x^2 }}}}\frac{{\partial ^2 }}{{\partial x^2 }}
$

Comment: that is not the correct transformation rule for second derivatives. Under a coordinate transformation $y = y(x)$, you have $\partial_x \to \partial_x y \cdot \partial_y$, but the second derivative transforms like $\partial_x^2 \to (\partial_x y)^2 \partial_y^2 + l.o.t.$, where $l.o.t.$ stands for first order derivatives.

Comment: @Willie: Okay, then could you follow a similar transformation and post an alternate answer?